# Reusable component for different pages in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a reusable component in rectjs, but i need to know which is the best a approach for doing this. The idea is next:

I have a form in my application. This form (the same design, but different inputs and different number of inputs) is almost on all pages of my application. I thought, maybe i should create this component as a reusable one, but i need a good approach. Who knows which will be the best solution in this case? To create a reusable component or to create for each page one form with own logic?

Comment: Any code about your implementation?

Comment: @keikai, i want now to start, but also i need the best approach, and if is a reason to create a reusable component.

Comment: Kindly check the official document would help.

Comment: Since the from has different `input` on different pages the simplest approach would be to create a different form for each page or if you want to have a single form , you could use conditional rendering based on the page but it is up to you how you want to do it,Since the task can be done in numerous ways

Comment: I think, by definition, all react components are *reusable*. Please share what you've attempted and what specific issue you have.